# read_csv appends a .1 to column name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I just noticed a strange problem when reading a csv file with pandas read_csv.

When I open my file in an editor the header looks like this (there are a lot of columns so I skip most of them by adding `...` here):

```
tag_identifier,a,article,aside,b,body,br,button,circle,clippath,dd,defs,desc,div,dl,dt,em,fecolormatrix,...,uses_most_common_font_family,uses_most_common_font_size,uses_most_common_font_family_and_size,is_article
```

When I now do a `df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv-file.csv")`

and the I check the columns like this: `print(df.columns.tolist())`

I suddently get this output:

```
['tag_identifier', 'a', 'article', 'aside', 'b', 'body', 'br', 'button' ..., 'title', 'tspan', 'ul', 'use', 'a.1', 'article.1', 'aside.1', 'b.1', 'body.1', 'br.1', 'button.1', ... ]
```

As you can see the column names that correspond to a html tag are copied and a `.1` is appended.

For example the `body` tag is copied and set to `body.1`.

So eventually I have now two columns: `body` and `body.1` which I can both access via `df["body"]` and `df["body.1"]`.

Even stranger, this only happens to the html-tag column names. All other column names are unaffected.

Has anybody an idea what could cause this issue?

Comment: you can rename the columns by some simple regex or even better melt them and then re-create your dataframe as long as opposed to wide, so your html tags are variables instead of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you have duplicate column names. Rename them or if they're really duplicate get rid of them in the data.
Anyway, you can filter them out using Pandas tools.

Comment: You`re right. Okay, then I made an error previously to creating this csv file. Anyways thanks for mentioning.